# Issues with xAxis labels and useHTML #1

Tags: highcharts

I am having an issue with xAxis labels and useHTML:

We are wrapping the xAxis label in a div with an onclick method to call another JS function. This can be seen here...

http://jsfiddle.net/yg2SF/1/

However, if you click the xAxis label, nothing happens...

To fix this, i changed the useHTML flag to true, as seen here...you will notice that now the onclick method works.

```
useHTML:true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yg2SF/2/

However, now the labels are wrapping unnecessarily...you can see that the xAxis labels now span 2 lines.  Why is this and how can i address this?

Comment: While i don't know why the label formatting doesn't work properly when useHTML is true, I do know that if I use a <a> tag instead of a <div> everything works properly.  This can be demonstrated here...http://jsfiddle.net/yg2SF/6/

Answer (score 2):

Set style width for your labels inline, see: http://jsfiddle.net/yg2SF/8/

```
            formatter: function() {
                return '<div style="width:70px" onclick="alert(\''+this.value+'\')">'+this.value+'</div>';    
            }
```

To your comment:
`<a>` tags are translated to SVG, `<div>` tags with custom onclick aren't.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of Highchart is to wrap the label value in a `<tspan>` tag inside of a `<text>` tag. Both of those tags seem to get "white-space: nowrap" as a default browser behavior so they do not wrap.

Your jsFiddle example is specifically setting the white-space to "normal" which will allow the text wrap when appropriate. It is acceptable to wrap text on a hyphen so your labels with "Jan-2005" (et al) are going to wrap. If you simply remove the "whiteSpace: 'normal'," element from the style block, they no longer wrap. If you really wanted to make sure they do not wrap you could even change it "whiteSpace: 'nowrap',".

Additionally, the example you linked in your comment does not use HTML so Highchart is actually stripping out your `<a>` tag but is nice enough to convert your href="javascript:alert()" code into an onclick event for the `<tspan>`